# HornetQ and ActiveMQ CMS don't work together!

Tags: c++, content-management-system, hornetq, activemq-cpp

I'm trying to implement a solution using HornetQ. Since I need to access it through a C++ application, that raises me a problem. I'm compiling the activemq-cpp builtin example, and changing it to work with stomp instead of openwire (HornetQ doesn't understand openwire). The application refuses to produce messages on the intended queue. Seems that a lot of people are having the same issue, but no one has the answer. (someone said it's a bug on the cms API)

Anyone has a pratical example of HornetQ working with a C++ app?

PS: Obviously the activemq-cpp example works with an activemq server using openwire.

Answer (score 2):

HornetQ is probably mapping destination names differently then the ActiveMQ C++ Stomp client, for instance in ActiveMQ a topic destination is prefixed with /topic/ and a queue is /queue/.  I beleive this is different in HornetQ but not really sure.  You may want to look in their docs for what they use, if its configurable then you could alter it to match what the CMS client is sending.  You could also modify your local copy of CMS to send the destination name using the HornetQ prefix.

Regards
Tim.

www.fusesource.com

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have seen is a HornetQ to ActiveMQ bridge written in java then have the C++ app work with ActiveMQ.  You might be able to do something with JNI to handle marshaling messages into your app.